# iOS Simulator (11.1) that comes with Xcode 11.1 GM Seed seems to be unable to boot iOS 13.1 devices

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, ios13

I am running Mac OS X Mojave 10.14.6. The only app I have installed is a freshly downloaded Xcode 11.1 GM Seed (11A1027). There are no prior files, projects or apps on this system, as I just wanted to start learning Swift programming.

In Xcode, I have created a fresh project for a single view iOS app. I compiled it without any changes, the build was successful. By default, it launches an iPhone 11 Pro Max on iOS 13.1.

The Simulator launched, the device window appeared and a progress bar was going for a while. After some time, a spinning indicator appeared on a black screen, but nothing ever happened. This went on for a couple minutes, after which Xcode showed this error:

The request to open "com.example.FoodTracker" failed. Unexpected error type.

```
Details:

The request to open "com.example.FoodTracker" failed.
Domain: FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain
Code: 5
Failure Reason: Unexpected error type.
User Info: {
    BSErrorCodeDescription = InvlaidResponse;
}
--
The operation couldn't be completed.
(BSServiceConnectionErrorDomain error 3.)
Domain: BSServiceConnectionErrorDomain
Code: 3
User Info: {
    BSErrorCodeDescription = OperationFailed;
}
--
```

I left the device running in Simulator for quite some time but it never stopped spinning.

I have tried reinstalling Xcode, I deleted the DerivedData directory, did a clean build, reinstalled some Xcode components, but I think there is no issue with Xcode, or the project itself.

In the Simulator, I also tried to "Erase All Contents and Settings", quite a few times, to no avail.
I tried starting new devices and an iPhone 6s on iOS 12.2 loaded successfully on the first try. On the other hand, I kept trying iOS 13.1 with iPhone 11 Pro Max and iPhone 8 devices, but both get stuck after some loading.

Sometimes I also get this: SpringBoard quit unexpectedly. When I check the details, it seems that a SIGILL terminates it.

Anytime I start an iPhone 11 Pro Max device with iOS 13.1, it keeps spinning endlessly. After checking the system logs, I noticed that the same messages keep looping with ~5s delays inbetween:

```
Sep 29 08:17:22 Peterdis-iMac SpringBoard[2774]: objc[2774]: Class UIDelayedAction is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore (0x1247c9630) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/KeyboardArbiter.framework/KeyboardArbiter (0x10a3e4a60). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Sep 29 08:17:22 Peterdis-iMac SpringBoard[2774]: objc[2774]: Class UIHeldAction is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore (0x1247c9680) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/KeyboardArbiter.framework/KeyboardArbiter (0x10a3e4ab0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Sep 29 08:17:22 Peterdis-iMac SpringBoard[2774]: objc[2774]: Class SPXPCConnection is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Search.framework/Search (0x130d5a858) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpotlightUI.framework/SpotlightUI (0x10b4a1e30). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Sep 29 08:17:22 Peterdis-iMac SpringBoard[2774]: objc[2774]: Class SPXPCServer is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Search.framework/Search (0x130d5a8d0) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpotlightUI.framework/SpotlightUI (0x10b4a1ea8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Sep 29 08:17:22 Peterdis-iMac SpringBoard[2774]: objc[2774]: Class SPXPCMessage is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Search.framework/Search (0x130d5a880) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpotlightUI.framework/SpotlightUI (0x10b4a1e58). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Sep 29 08:17:22 Peterdis-iMac SpringBoard[2774]: objc[2774]: Class SPApplication is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Search.framework/Search (0x130d5a448) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpotlightUI.framework/SpotlightUI (0x10b4a1f20). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Sep 29 08:17:22 Peterdis-iMac SpringBoard[2774]: objc[2774]: Class AFUIPreferences is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SiriUI.framework/SiriUI (0x10de1a5c8) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssistantUI.framework/AssistantUI (0x12a0fb790). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Sep 29 08:17:22 Peterdis-iMac SpringBoard[2774]: objc[2774]: Class SBFBokehWallpaperColorArbiter is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardFoundation.framework/SpringBoardFoundation (0x10dce3dd8) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardHome.framework/SpringBoardHome (0x107450800). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Sep 29 08:17:22 Peterdis-iMac SpringBoard[2774]: objc[2774]: Class SBFMotionGestureController is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardFoundation.framework/SpringBoardFoundation (0x10dce2050) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoard.framework/SpringBoard (0x105a7fde0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Sep 29 08:17:24 Peterdis-iMac SpringBoard[2774]: assertion failed: 18G103 17A844: libxpc.dylib + 83383 [F391B106-5033-3156-98D9-705C5A7FDECD]: 0x7d
Sep 29 08:17:25 Peterdis-iMac com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.FA4A0BF0-0673-484C-896D-178314FAFAFF[2657] (com.apple.SpringBoard[2774]): Service exited due to SIGILL | sent by exc handler[2774]
Sep 29 08:17:25 Peterdis-iMac com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.FA4A0BF0-0673-484C-896D-178314FAFAFF[2657] (com.apple.SpringBoard): Skipping remaining event endpoints for importance boosting.
Sep 29 08:17:25 Peterdis-iMac com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.FA4A0BF0-0673-484C-896D-178314FAFAFF[2657] (com.apple.SpringBoard): Skipping remaining instance endpoints for importance boosting.
```

I've spent all day googling for solutions but nothing helped so far.
I guess in the meantime I will just start developing for 12.2, assuming that the basics are not too different. Although Xcode clearly generates code for 13.0+ and it yells at me that "some", "View" and such are for newer versions.

Comment: When in this state, run 'sudo sysdiagnose -q' and 'xcrun simctl diagnose'.  File a radar (http://bugreport.apple.com) and include the resulting tarballs as well as the bundle id for your app and a rough timestamp of when you hit the problem.  There's not enough in your report here to provide you with a solution, and it's working fine for everyone else...

Comment: One common way that things can go wrong with the simulator is through third party kexts that act as either antivirus software, or network activity monitors, or things like that.  Run `sudo kextstat -l | grep -v 'com.apple'` and see if anything suspicious appears.  If so, try uninstalling that software (and rebooting).

Answer (score 101, accepted):

I had the same issue.
Disabling AVX/AVX2 solved for me.

```
VBoxManage setextradata "$vm_name" VBoxInternal/CPUM/IsaExts/AVX 0
VBoxManage setextradata "$vm_name" VBoxInternal/CPUM/IsaExts/AVX2 0
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexandr!
I had a quite similar issue and your answer solved it (I am running a Mac on VirtualBox)

Comment: Very nice man! I am using Oracle Virtualbox last version in 14.01.2020.

Comment: I seem to have a similar problem, but this does not seem to work for me.  :-(

Comment: YOU SAVED MY LIFE <3 <3 <3

Comment: I spent 3 days googling and re-installing things, nothing worked until this solution. Thanks!

Comment: You are the chosen one, thank you so much, had many hours trying everything, this solves it!

Comment: Even after such a big delay, this proved to be useful with newer versions too.

Comment: It was a UB, but this answer saved me.

Comment: OMG! I spend several days and tried almost everything. This solution worked for me too. Thanks bro

Comment: Thank you! I wish I could've found this 2 days ago

Answer (score 18):

yeah,  this solution works.

Open cmd

1. `cd "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\"`
2. `VBoxManage setextradata "$vm_name" VBoxInternal/CPUM/IsaExts/AVX 0`
3. `VBoxManage setextradata "$vm_name" VBoxInternal/CPUM/IsaExts/AVX2 0`

Comment: How is an MS-DOS script a solution for a problem running the iOS simulator on a Macintosh?

Comment: because this issue is the result of running a mac os on VBox running on a windows machine (virtual mac). and changing the above values seems to solve the issue