# ios simulator stuck on apple logo on Virtual Box

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, virtualbox

I`m using mac os by installing it on the virtual box on my windows computer. I have installed Xcode. When I open the iOS simulator it will show a progress bar and later shows the apple logo. Then it will not go further. Always showing the apple logo and simulator will not open the UI. 
Has anyone a solution?

Comment: Make sure the ram limit is high. The simulator takes up a lot of RAM and CPU

Comment: @WonixerA I used 5GB of ram for virtual mac os

Comment: Can't you use your mac, not virtual box?

Comment: @WonixerA I'm still a student and I can`t afford a mac yet

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS Simulator (11.1) that comes with Xcode 11.1 GM Seed seems to be unable to boot iOS 13.1 devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58156879/ios-simulator-11-1-that-comes-with-xcode-11-1-gm-seed-seems-to-be-unable-to-bo)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If anyone has the same issue here is the solution I found.
check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58466749/10393174

Add "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\" into your system variables and run below commands in cmd

```
VBoxManage setextradata "$vm_name" VBoxInternal/CPUM/IsaExts/AVX 0
VBoxManage setextradata "$vm_name" VBoxInternal/CPUM/IsaExts/AVX2 0
```