# I can't open the ios emulator, how to fix it?

Tags: ios, macos, ios-simulator, springboard

[image]

I can't open the iOS emulator, how to fix it?

NB: I'm using Oracle VM VirtualBox.

Comment: are you using VMWare or something to sandbox?

Comment: I'm using Oracle VM VirtualBox.

Comment: windows machine?

Comment: Read this, it may be useful for you https://twitter.com/steipete/status/1167903945307512832?s=21

Comment: Thanks so much everyone, I can open it now.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open CMD and navigate to VirtualBox directory

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\"
VBoxManage setextradata "YourVMName" VBoxInternal/CPUM/IsaExts/AVX 0
VBoxManage setextradata "YourVMName" VBoxInternal/CPUM/IsaExts/AVX2 0
```

Orignal [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58466749/4061501)